# Julia DataFrames countmap()

Tags: julia

Edit: countmap() is in StatsBase.jl and is working as expected. I'm not sure how to change this to an answered problem or if I should I delete it.

```
using DataFrames
using CSV

train = DataFrame(CSV.File("training.csv"))
countmap(train.column)



UndefVarError: countmap not defined

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ In[40]:1
 [2] eval
   @ .\boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [3] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
   @ Base .\loading.jl:1094
```

I get that error running the code. Was countmap deprecated at some point and I just cannot find any updates about it or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for [`countmap`](https://juliastats.org/StatsBase.jl/stable/counts/#StatsBase.countmap) from the [StatsBase.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/StatsBase.jl) package?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following pattern to get a `DataFrame` instead of a `Dict` as a result:

```
combine(groupby(train, :column), nrow)
```

(in many cases it will be much faster than `countmap`)

Also instead of:

```
DataFrame(CSV.File("training.csv"))
```

it is more efficient to write:

```
CSV.read("training.csv", DataFrame)
```